# Typescript: Contraint a type to be array

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

How do you constraint a type parameter T to be an array in Typescript. For example I want to create a type that accepts an array type and let's just say wraps it in another level. Something like

```
type WrapIt<T extends T[]> = [T]; // Doesn't do what I want.
```

Comment: Are you looking for `T extends any[]`?

Comment: Ah, that's it. Thanks @Artyer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the generic constraint to be `any[]`. Because it's generic, the array type will be inferred, and the result will not actually be `any`.

```
type WrapIt<T extends any[]> = [T];

type A = WrapIt<string[]> // [string[]]
```

[Playgrond](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=3.8.3&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=3&pc=40#code/C4TwDgpgBA6gTgQzASWAHgCpQgD2BAOwBMBnKBAkAbQF0A+KAXiioxoG4BYAKB9EigBBJrEQp0JYHACWBAOa0GAeiUtJM+bRpA)

Comment: Thanks, @Alex. This does what I want. However, I am not sure why `any[]` works but not `T[]`. If anything, am I not being more specific?

Comment: How can `T` extend `T[]`? `T` has to mean the same thing everywhere it's used. That's like saying `string extends string[]` which could never be true. So typescript gives you an error.

Comment: Ah, got it. Thanks once again.

Comment: Glad it helped @SajalKhandelwal. Don'y forget to accept the answer that best helped you by clicking the checkmark.